# bitmap image not showing

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Im getting an image from database and trying to display in a imageview with no success - image is not showing. What could be wrong here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + "images/thumb/" + imageUrl);//("/sdcard/image.jpg");
                                            ImageView im = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                                            im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For download and display image you can use a library [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
String imageUrl = PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + "images/thumb/" + imageUrl;
ImageView im = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(im);
```

Or if you need Bitmap of image:

```
String imageUrl = PHP_MYSQL_SITE_URL + "images/thumb/" + imageUrl;
ImageView im = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(new Target() {

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                            im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: But i also need to save the image in a variable and sent it to the next activity as bitmap and it does not work

Comment: @noob if you need to save image you also need to use Picasso Target. Check my answer, i added example with Picasso Target

Comment: Instead of Picasso, Glide can be used since it have offline caching out of the box.